# subdomain redirects to subfolder

Tags: domain, redirect, subdomain, directory

I have created a subdomain for my website (fr.mohamedkadri.com) and after 24 hours it became active but it redirects to the subfolder that I poited to (mohamedkadri.com/fr)

Is there a problem? why the subdomain redirects to the subfolder?

here is my .htaccess:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mohamedkadri.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mohamedkadri.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: so the problem is in the htaccess! but how to make it enforce the url without www and keep other subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

1. You could add a more rewrite conditions

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mohamedkadri.com$ [NC]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^fr.mohamedkadri.com$ [NC]

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mohamedkadri.com/$1 [L,R=301]
2. You could setup [apache virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/), so each domain would have its own configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think its a good solution but I got a simpler way.

Comment: The answers do the same thing in different ways: Your's leaves everything alone but www.mohamedkadri.com.  Mine redirects everything to mohamedkadri.com except for fr.mohamedkadri.com.  Depending on your goal, either one could be best.

Answer (score 0):

afaik subdomains are stored in subfolders (e.g. apache). as long as you can reach your target via the intended fr.mohamedkadri.com/and/more/URL where is the problem?

**Edit0:**
Imho you have to use rewrite rules (apache mod_rewrite) in your `.htaccess` file in the folder named according to your subdomain.

Comment: the problem is that when I write fr.mohamedkadri.com I get mohamedkadri.com/fr/, the subfolder that the subdomain "fr" is pointing to

Comment: so a larger url must be like fr.mohamedkadri.com/anything-else and not mohamedkadri.com/fr/anyting-else

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the point!

I eidted my htaccess file:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mohamedkadri.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$

to

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.mohamedkadri.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$

So I got the www removed and other subdomains kept as is!

Thanks for your replies ;)